# PHP/MySQL Retrieve the last action of each user to make a list

Tags: php, mysql

i m developing a dynamic website but i have a problem with a query. I m trying to build a map dynamically by retrieving date from the database. I enclose the db structure:

countries (code, name)

data (user_id, dateaction, container)

users (user_id, country_code)

I want to display a list of the AVG container for each country, but the average value should be calculated from last action of each user and the data should be submitted the current day. In the case of non-value of "container" for any country the value is 0. I tried many queries but i couldnt achieve the target. I attach some of the queries i tried.

```
$query = "SELECT AVG(data.container), data.user_id, users.country_code ".
"FROM data, users ".
"WHERE data.user_id = users.user_id AND dateaction >= '".date('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00'."' AND date < '".date('Y-m-d').' 23:59:59'."'".
"GROUP BY users.country_code ";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $cid=$row['country_code'];
    $queryy=mysql_query("select * FROM Countries WHERE country_code='$cid'") or die("Error Occured,plz try again1");
    $rowy = mysql_fetch_array( $queryy );
    $cname=$rowy['country_name'];
    echo '<area title="'.strtoupper($cname).'" mc_name="'.strtoupper($cid).'"></area>'; }
```

Please may you help me to solve this logical problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT a.user_id, ifnull(a.country_code, 0) as country_code, avg(a.container) ".
"FROM data a INNER JOIN ".
"(SELECT data.user_id, max(dateaction) dateaction ".
"FROM data".
"WHERE dateaction >= '".date('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00'."' AND date < '".date('Y-m-d').' 23:59:59'."'".
"GROUP BY data.user_id) b ".
"ON a.user_id = b.user_id and a.date_action = b.date_action ".
"GROUP BY a.user_id, ifnull(a.country_code, 0) "
```

Comment: Thank you for the instant reply!!! Actually, the list i want to appear is like to below:Andorra 0 (if no one submit sth)
United Arab Emirates 15 (the average of the value of rows that submitted today from users. From each user we calculate only the last submit. So 1st user submitted: 14,16,20 and the 2nd use: 8,10. The average is a calculation of 20 and 10, the average of the last submissions of each user from this country). How can i display it? does the previous query fulfill this execution?

Comment: I tried the query you posted but i received "Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'isnull'"... :/

Comment: i'm sorry, my brain was in MSSQL mode, it's IFNULL in MySQL, i'll edit the code